Cache HTML e CSS
Eai pessoal! Atualizei o meu site e principalmente o css novo que eu coloquei ficou desatualizado. Limpei meu cache do navegador e descobri que era por conta disso. O ponto é o seguinte: O cliente provavelmente não limpa cache e não vai pensar o que eu pensei
Como fazer para que o cliente não precise ter problemas com cache?

Não repita perguntas, restaure a pergunta original e siga as orientações fornecidas, se precisa comentar também faça na pergunta original.
